# Swiper add class to current slide when pa

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper JS to create a slider. I would like to add a class to the active (current) slide when the page loads and also when the slide changes. Then remove the class when the slide is not active.

It works fine when the slide changes but when the slider initialize it doesn't. How can I add the class when slider init? I tried `swiperText.on('init'...` but it doesn't work.

The JS:

```
const swiperText = new Swiper('.js-swiper', {
    autoplay: {
        delay: 2000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true,
    speed: 1200,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    autoHeight: true
});

swiperText.on('slideChange', function (e) {
    const index_currentSlide = this.realIndex;
    const currentSlide = this.slides[index_currentSlide]

    currentSlide.classList.add("is-red");
});
```

Thank you.